# Bad Request from WCF Service using httpclient postAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, wcf, httpclient

Following is the my wcf service.

```
  public ApiResponseWrapper<TextBlobModel> PostText(string sessionId, string profileId, TextBlobModel txtModel)
    {}
```

Interface part for this is

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "session/{sessionId}/profile/{profileId}/text")]
    ApiResponseWrapper<TextBlobModel> PostText(string sessionId, string profileId, TextBlobModel txtModel);
```

And Model is

```
 [DataContract]
public class TextBlobModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string text { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
    public DateTime receivedTime { get; set; }
}
```

When i called above service by following way i always get Bad Request Error.

```
          var baseApiUrl = "http://localhost:51398/api.svc/";
           HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient();
           authClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseoAuthApiUrl);
           apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

           var txtModel = new TextBlobModel();
           txtModel.text = "Hello How are you";
           txtModel.receivedTime = DateTime.Now;

            HttpResponseMessage txtResponse = apiClient.PostAsJsonAsync(String.Format("session/{0}/profile/{1}/text", "sessionId", "profileId"), txtModel).Result;
            var txtData = txtResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>().Result;
```

See following image.

[image]

Can you please suggest what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should put the calling code in try catch and try to get the web error details to get the actual reason for this error

Comment: I get Bad Request error from this line  HttpResponseMessage txtResponse = apiClient.PostAsJsonAsync(String.Format("session/{0}/profile/{1}/text", sessionResponseData.sessionId, addProfileObj.id), txtModel).Result;

Comment: try my code to get the actual error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, change UriTemplate

```
"session/{sessionId}/profile/{profileId}/text"
```

to

```
"PostText/session/{sessionId}/profile/{profileId}/text".
```

try this 'BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest',

and Add this to config file to add trace log and after that you will get actual error.

```
<configuration> 
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
</trace> 
<sources> 
<source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Critical,Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
<listeners> 
<add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\messages.svclog" />
</listeners>
</source> 
</sources> 
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you can use fiddler tool for response, or you can add log.

Comment: I tried your solutiuon as well but not working also the same url if i tried on rest client is working fine 

http://localhost:51398/api.svc/session/testSession4991054/profile/H9YEHNCBAPWB/text
Issue is only with httpclient

Comment: If it is working in rest client plugin, then there must be some parameter or header, which is creating issue. try to find out that.

Comment: that's why i post the question here with code that i am using for calling that wcf service if you are able to see what parameter or header is missing here please specify....else allows other to answer it ;-)

Comment: I can't see, and also can't stop others to answer :p

Comment: try this 'BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest'

Comment: After changing this It hits the API but passing null for txtModel instead of model values.

Comment: you have add [DataContract] and [DataMember] in model?

Comment: <configuration> <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
    </trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Critical,Information,ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="C:\logs\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics> </configuration>         Add this to config file to add trace log and after that you will get actual error.

Comment: Please update you answer, I will mark that as answer, error tracing helped my problem issue is with the serialization of date object.